# IIS URL Rewrite root only

Tags: iis

I have 2 URLs 
    http://test.mysite.com (1) and 
    http://test.mysite.com/app (2)

I would like to redirect requests to (1) to www.othersite.com 
when (2) shuld not be redirected.

Is it possible to do with url rewrite using regex?

br

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible with URL rewrite module. Your rule looks like that:

```
<rule name="Redirect non app" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^app(.*)" negate="true" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.othersite.com{REQUEST_URI}" />
</rule>
```